# How to use value from file_get_contents php as a number?

Tags: php, string, operators, file-get-contents

How to use value from `file_get_contents` php as a number ?

I want to use `$val` in this case = `50.0001` plus with `20` it's will be result `70.0001` But when i test it's show `0` why ? how can i do ?

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$node = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'test')]");
$val = $doc->saveHTML($node->item(0));
$result = $val + 20;
echo $result;
?>
```

and https://www.example.com

```
<span class="test">50.0001</span>
```

Comment: Can you var_dump to $node and $val?

Answer (score 0):

just get the textcontent from the node and don't use saveHTML.

```
$val = $node->item(0)->textContent;
```